# Orthonormality of Hermite function

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-functions

I was wondering if someone could tell me when the following relation holds?
where $H_{n}(x)$ are Hermite polynomials and $\delta(x-x')$ is Dirac delta function:
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty
\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}2^{n}n!}
e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^{2}-\frac{1}{2}x'^{2}}
H_{n}(x)H_{n}(x')
= 
\delta(x-x')
.
$$

I asked this because I am trying to solve this:

https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/455890/photon-number-representation-of-a-position-eigenstate

Comment: For all real $x$ and $x’$, I would assume.

Comment: how may i proceed to prove it? @G.Smith

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials#Completeness_relation

Comment: I have a related question, ado the same completeness relations exist for any orthonomal basis dense in L^2? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Denote the left hand side of your identity by $K(x,x’)$. The identity $K(x,x’)=\delta(x-x’)$ is an identity between generalized functions. What it’s really saying is that
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} K(x,x’)f(x’)dx’ = f(x)
$$
for any $x$ and any reasonably nice function $f$. In fact it’s enough to prove this for $f(x)=e^{-x^2/2} H_m(x)$ a Hermite function, since the Hermite functions are s complete orthogonal system in $L_2(\mathbb{R})$. For this $f$ the claim follows immediately from the orthogonality relation for the Hermite polynomials, since when we perform the integration for the $n$th term in the sum, we get 0 if $n \neq m$ and the correct thing for $n=m$.